# Can it be proven rigorously?

Tags: real-analysis

Can it be proven rigorously that if $$x^2 \leq \epsilon$$
for any arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, then $$x = 0$$

Comment: It follows from the Archimedean property and continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ at $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that for all $\epsilon>0$, $x^2\le\epsilon$. Let's assume $x\ne0$. What about when $\epsilon=\frac{x^2}2$? Does this lead to a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

Statement:

If $0\leq v$ and $v \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ then $v=0$

proof: If $S$ is the set of all numbers $v>0$ having this property and $S$ is not empty, then $S$ has an upper bound, hence a supremum $\mu$, which must be greater than $0$. Take $\epsilon = {\mu \over 2} < \mu$, by definition of the supremum there is a $v \in S$ such that
$$
{\mu \over 2} < v \leq \mu
$$
But for $\epsilon:={\mu \over 2}$ you must have $v \leq \epsilon$.

Now use that $x=0$ iff $|x|=0$ iff $x^2=0$ and apply this to $v=x^2$

Comment: To construct your set you need $\epsilon$ which you later say is equal to one half of the sets supremum. I doubt this circular definition counts as a rigorous proof.

Comment: Nope, $S:= \{ v > 0 | v \leq \epsilon \text{ for all } \epsilon >0 \} $ has nothing to do with any epsilon. There is nothing circular here.